# How to send multiple forms data in one shot to server using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have two forms in one html page. Below is the structure.

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>

<form name="form2">
    <input type="text" name="address" />
    <input type="text" name="state" />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

On clicking on the next submit button of first form i want to validate first form and i want to scroll to second form and disable the first form.

On clicking on the next submit button of form2 i want to validate second form and i want to submit data to server using $http from both forms(form1 and form2). 
May i know is this is possible to achieve this? Also may i know is this is the right way i am following or something else i have to do with above requirement? Any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes its possible. You just have to capture the values of first form and on submitting second form, use formData to append all values that u have captured.

Comment: Hi Vivz. Thanks. After clicking on the first submit button i can validate first form and scroll to second form and finally i am able to capture data from both forms and submit it?

Comment: How can i capture data from multiple forms? $scope.modelname?

Comment: Are both the forms within the scope of same controller? I will suggest you to bind all the properties of both forms to a common object

Comment: Yes same controller.

Comment: Then you can do as I said above , bind to a common object. But if you don't need two forms as suggested in one of the answers you can go with that, but validations will be a lot easier with form tags in angularjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151563/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-vivz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind all your values to a common object. I am enabling the second form after submitting the first form. In second forms submit function, you just have to loop through the values of common object and append it to `formData`. If you don't have any reason for having two forms, you can consolidate it into one.

**Note**: I have not added any form validations. For adding form validations, please refer https://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/xFcdI

**HTML**:

```
<form name="form1" ng-submit="enableForm2()">
    <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="obj.fname" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="obj.lname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>

<form name="form2" ng-show="enableForm" ng-submit="finalSubmit()">
    <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="obj.address" />
    <input type="text" name="state" ng-model="obj.state" />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

**JS**:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.obj = {};
     $scope.enableForm = false;
     $scope.enableForm2 = function() {
         $scope.enableForm = true;
     }
     $scope.finalSubmit = function() {
         $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: YourURL,
             withCredentials: true,
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': undefined
             },
             data: {},
             transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                 var formData = new FormData();
                 angular.forEach($scope.obj, function(value, key) {
                     formData.append(key, value);
                 })
                 return formData;
             }
         }).then(function(data) {
            $scope.enableForm=false;
           }).catch(function(data, status) {

          })
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive it vai an Ajax Call not by direct Submit. Moreover Form Submit is not required. (Adding Form tag is optional)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Personal Info</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="form1.fname" name="fname"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="form1.lname" name="lname"/>
<input type="button" ng-click="SubmitForm()" value="Next"/>


<p>Address Info</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="form2.address" name="address"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="form2.state" name="state"/>
<input type="button" ng-click="SubmitForm()" value="Next"/>


</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $q, HTTPService) {

        $scope.form1 = {
          fname: '',
          lname: ''
        };
        
        $scope.form2 = {
          address: '',
          state: ''
        };
        
        $scope.SubmitForm = function () {
            
            let submitFormData = {
              form1: $scope.form1,
              form2: $scope.form2
            };
        
            HTTPService.SubmitData(submitFormData);
        }
        
    });
 
 app.factory('HTTPService', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            SubmitData: function (formData) {
            let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:2000/...';
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: apiUrl + "SaveData.php",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": '',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                },
                data: formData
            };

            var result = $http(req)
            .then(function(response) {
                return angular.fromJson(response.data);
            }, function(response) {
                return null;
            });

            return result;
        },
        };
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using $scope also you will get values of fields which are not in same form.

Answer (score 1):

> HTML Code

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
<form name="myForm">
<!-- first nested form -->
  <div ng-form="form1">
    <label><p>Personal Info</p></label>    
    <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="myForm.fname"/>
    <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="myForm.lname"/>
  </div>
<!-- second nested form -->
 <div ng-form="form2">
    <label><p>Address Info</p></label>
    <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="myForm.address"/>
    <input type="text" name="state" ng-model="myForm.state"/>
</div>
<!-- etc. -->
<input type="submit" ng-click="SubmitForm()" value="Next"/>
</form>
</div>
```

> JS/Controller code

```
 var app = angular.module('App');

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.SubmitForm = function () {
        var SubmitForm = $scope.myForm;
        console.log(SubmitForm);
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do someting like below

```
<form name="form1" ng-submit="moveNext(user)">
   <input type="text" ng-model="user.fname" name="fname" required/>
   <input type="text" ng-model="user.fname" name="lname" required/>
   <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
<form name="form2" ng-submit="submit(addressData)">
   <input type="text" ng-model="addressData.address" name="address"/>
   <input type="text" ng-model="addressData.state" name="state"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

and in Controller

```
$scope.userDetails = {};
$scope.addressDetails = {};
$scope.moveNext = function(userData){
    $scope.userDetails = userData //Save user Data here and implement logic to scroll to next form and validation
}

$scope.submit = function(addressData){
  $scope.addressDetails = addressData; 
  // and validate the form and Submit data to server here as per your requirement 
}
```